# How to list Activities which match an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a few separate applications which are all launched purely through a main application.

I am wondering if I'd be able to use intents to retrieve a list of all the sub-applications which match some discovery intent.

The main application currently needs to know what Intents to use to START these sub-applications, but is there a way to use intents to see if other Activities on the device match a set of intent-filters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am wondering if I'd be able to use
> intents to retrieve a list of all the
> sub-applications which match some
> discovery intent.

Absolutely. Use `PackageManager`, and probably the `queryIntentActivities()` method, to achieve your goals.

[This old sample Java code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/Introspection/Launchalot/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/launchalot/Launchalot.java) demonstrates finding all launcher activities via `queryIntentActivities()`.